# How to get the webpage rendered by javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I want to get a webpage.

The url is https://land.3fang.com/LandAssessment/b6d8b2c8-bd4f-4bd4-9d22-ca49a7a2dc1f.html.

The webpage will generate two values with javascript.

Just input 5 in the text box and press the red button.

Two values in red will be returned.

Please refer to the following image.

[image]

I tried using `pyqt5`, `requests_html` and `pyppeteer`.

Here is the code for `pyqt5`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Render(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.html = ""
        self.first_pass = True
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        super(Render, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._load_finished)
        self.loadProgress.connect(print)
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _load_finished(self, result):
        if result:
            self.call_js()

    def call_js(self):
        self.runJavaScript('document.getElementById("txtDistance").value = "5";')
        self.runJavaScript("void(0)")
        self.runJavaScript("CheckUserWhere();")
        self.toHtml(self.callable)

    def callable(self, data):
        self.html = data
        self.app.quit()

url = "https://land.3fang.com/LandAssessment/b6d8b2c8-bd4f-4bd4-9d22-ca49a7a2dc1f.html"
web = Render(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(web.html, 'html.parser')
_bpgj = soup.find('b', {'id':"_bpgj"}).string
_bSumPrice = soup.find('b', {'id':"_bSumPrice"}).string
print(_bpgj, _bSumPrice)
```

However, the results are either the IDLE restarts or there no response for a long time.

How to do it correctly?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use `selenium`. But, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried pyqt5, requests_html and pyppeteer.but all failed.

Comment: Show us your code, then we can investigate what makes it error.

Comment: The code for `pyqt5` has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Since your page is rendered using Javascript, you need a web driver like selenium that can render javascript content.

Checkout the following question as well for better existing answers
[Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8049520/7515189)